# Controlling map details shown using Leaflet and MapBox

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, mapbox, zoom

I am building a map based chart using Leaflet (with MapBox). I would like to know if there is a way to control the level of details displayed on the map when zooming in. For example I do not want to see Interstate highway or street names.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181679/level-of-detail-tuning-google-maps-api) explains how to do this using google maps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are at least two ways.

1. Leaflet's [zoomend event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend). For example:

   ```
   map.on('zoomend', function() {  
   var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();  
       if (zoomLevel > 10) map.removeLayer(highways);  
   });
   ```

   This is (very) incomplete. Most likely you will want to add and remove layers based on the current zoom level.

   Here is [an example from MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-only-at-zoom-level/) for hiding markers at specific zoom levels with this event, plus some custom MapBox methods.
2. `L.tileLayer` has options for [minZoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-minzoom) and [maxZoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-maxzoom). So, if you have access to tiles with and without labels (highways, etc.), you can pass these options when generating the tile layers:

   ```
   // tiles with labels for high zoom
   var withLabels = L.tileLayer(url, {
       maxZoom: 18,
       minZoom: 11,
   }).addTo(map);

   // tiles without labels for low zoom
   var noLabels = L.tileLayer(url, {
       maxZoom: 19,
       minZoom: 0,
   }).addTo(map);
   ```